# Create tables in Laravel 4 with Schema Builder without Migrations on shared hosting

Tags: laravel-4, database-schema

Well, I have a web application and I want to create a teable with Schema Builder, and I cannot Create a migration in a shared hosting, what can you suggest to make a table with Schema?

```
Schema::create('users', function($table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
});
```

ps. I want to use specifically Laravel's Schema Builder to create tables

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by creating migrations and a install route. From which you can call some thing like this 
`Artisan::call('migrate');`

for more info look at this [Run Artisan Commands Form Route or Controller](http://www.laravel-tricks.com/tricks/run-artisan-commands-form-route-or-controller)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Laravel's Routing to run schema builder ?

```
Route::get('/', function () {

    Schema::create('table', function($table) {

      $table->increments('id');

    });

    return "done.";

});
```